# FancyBox position in opera

Tags: fancybox, opera

The product is good.But I've got a problem - **in the opera** at the bottom of the image and can not see it. Although other browsers work fine. Can anyone give any solution to  this problem?

[Page](http://www.unecha.net/photoalbum/test.php) with the problem

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Day struggled with the problem - it turned out to work **in the opera** will be true only if you specify the **doctype page**. Details have not yet figured out.

Comment: a `DOCTYPE` is a good practice without saying a requirement for webpages to work properly. Check http://alistapart.com/article/doctype